# C program. files.

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault

Im working with files and this gives me an segmentation fault error after I compile it.
Im trying to open a file and save it in a vector. Also i would like to use dinamic memory to allocate it.

```
 #include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

main(){

  int n,v[n],i,c,cant;


  FILE*archivo;

  archivo = fopen("vectores.dat","wb");
    if(archivo == NULL)
    {
      printf("Error while opening");
      exit(1);
    }


  printf("write the number of integers you want to save in the file");
  scanf("%d",&cant);


  for(i=0;i<cant;i++){

    printf("write the number in the position:  %d",i+1);
    scanf("%d",v[i]);
  }


  c= fwrite(v,sizeof(int),n,archivo);
    if(c<1){

    printf("Error while writing");
    exit(1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a *big* problem:

```
int n,v[n],...
```

First you declare the variable `n`, but you don't initialize it, then you declare `v` as an array of `n` integers. The problem with this is that since `n` is uninitialized its value is *indeterminate*, and you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You later use `n` again, still without initialization.

If your program have undefined behavior anywhere, it's ill-formed and none of the code can be trusted.

Comment: Did you not realise that the programmer has a psychic compiler :-)

Comment: @EdHeal great!  Where can I download it?  Wanted one of those for decades.  A psychic linker would be even better, no more makefiles:)

Comment: @MartinJames - makefiles - that's old skool